# Comparisons of targeting models

Tags: references, ab-test

I need to compare two targeting models in an experiment. We will apply the same treatment to everyone who is targeted.

The experimental set up is as follows:

- The total population is split into three groups: A (10K), B (10K), C (4k)
- We then rank the population of Group A according to algorithm A and apply a treatment to the top 5k people.
- We rank the population of Group B according to algorithm B, and apply the same treatment to the top 5k.
- In Group C we do no ranking and apply no treatment.

My question is:

- How do we compare the success of each group?
- Do we compare the total number 'cured' after receiving the treatment in Groups A vs Group B?
- Do we compare the total 'cured' in A vs B (both compared to the control group C)?

Comment: Just to be clear: The lower 5k from groups A & B are untreated, correct? The actual "success" depends directly to your metric but unfortunately this is not elucidated in the question. I would also note that the top 5K from groups A & B are not random samples, there is a clear selection bias based on ranking the users prior to providing them with treatment.

Comment: Yes, the lower 5k are untreated. The metric is either total 'cured' amongst the treated or total 'cured' amongst the whole group. We are not sure which to use, and why.

Comment: Why would we use the latter? If anything 50% have not been treated so we just add noise to our metric. As mentioned though, there is a strong selection bias here because of the ranking step.

Comment: Why would we use the latter? There are those amongst the 5k who don't receive the 'treatment' who will go on to be 'cured' (the application isn't medical). I have been told that we have to include the possibility of them in our analysis.

Comment: 'As mentioned though, there is a strong selection bias here because of the ranking step.' That's exactly right, and I don't understand how to compare these groups given the different selection biases in the two different ranking steps.

Comment: Some context? What is the experiment about, in practical terms? Is [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22368245) what you are talking about?

Comment: The experiment is to compare different ranking strategies for marketing - the treatment is being contacted, being cured is activating a voucher code (or naturally reactivating if no voucher code was supplied to a customer).

Comment: We want to compare the total number of customers activating a voucher in groups A and B, but we're are unsure about whether we should compare just the targeted customers or the whole groups.

Comment: I think it is reasonable to make the randomisation after the ranking. i.e. you rank all 10K users in bin A and then 50% of them take the treatment associated with bin A. Then when making the comparison we use the known rank as an additional explanatory/control variable. EDIT: 1. Is the ranking methodology that is different between variants A & B or 2.  is the ranking methodology the same but the treatments are different or 3. both ranking and treatments are different between the bins?

Comment: The ranking methodology is what is different between groups A&B. The treatments are the same. We will be ranking all 10k customers, but taking the top 50% not a random 50%.